# How to remove the global execution permision on my ntfs partition on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, partitioning, permissions, ntfs

I have toyed with my `fstab` file to allow automatic mount and execution of scripts on my `ntfs` partition. I also played with file permission using `chmod +x -R`. At the begining nothing worked, but now, after reboot, every file in my `ntfs` folder has a 777 permission. How do I remove that?

This is the relevant line in my `fstab` file

```
UUID=D8F68113F680F2D4   /mnt/ntfs   ntfs    rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,
```

Comment: Did you tried with `UUID=D8F68113F680F2D4   /mnt/ntfs   ntfs   defaults,rw  0  0` ?

Comment: If I well understood what it happens you should mount with the `permission` option the  ntfs partition (`UUID=D8F68113F680F2D4   /mnt/ntfs   ntfs  auto,users,permissions  `... or something similar) and then modify the attributes again  with `chmod -x -R`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `umask` (for all files and directories), `dmask` (for directories), and/or `fmask` (for non-directory files) options, as in:

```
LABEL=Windows8_OS  /other/windows  ntfs  noauto,users,fmask=133,dmask=022  0  0
```

All of these `?mask` options say which permissions, in octal form, to *remove* from files. Thus, in this example, files will end up with 644 (`rw-r--r--`) and directories will have permissions of 755 (`rwxr-xr-x`). You can adjust the permissions as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

When you mount NFS, your permissions you're mounting it with must match up with what you have on the server. Looks to me like the server is exporting it with 777, change the server permissions.

Comment: The question is about the New Technology File System (NTFS), as used on Windows systems, not the Network File System (NFS), as used by Unix-like file servers.